# prompted, looped commands

Tags: command-line, interactive

Is there a general way to do unix command and loop it over a list of files. For example, let's imagine we wanted to move all the files (but not directories) in a directory to another directory, but get prompted y/n before each one. Obviously, this can be done with a script, but is there a single command way to do this not just for mv, but for any similar do-something-to-a-file action (rm, cat, wc, grep, etc)?

Comment: Tyler, did either answer solve your problem? If so, please click the checkmark next to it; if not, please clarify the question to explain. Thank you!

Comment: @JeffSchaller I will start voting for your answer when you start voting for my question.

Comment: I haven't voted against it, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

```
find /path/to/source/dir -type f -maxdepth 1 -ok mv {} /path/to/target/dir \;
```

The `find` command here will find all regular files in `/path/to/source/dir` and prompt the user for an ok to perform the given operation, which in this case will move the file to `/path/to/target/dir`. If the user presses `y` (and <kbd>enter</kbd>), the operation will be performed.

The `{}` will be replaced by the name of each found file in turn and the command that is executed for each file ends at `\;`.

If you replace `-ok` with `-exec`, the user will not be prompted, and the operation will be carried out on *all* files.

`-maxdepth 1` restricts the search for files to the topmost directory (`/path/to/source/dir`). Without it, `find` would recurse down into all subdirectories under the given path.

`-type f` restricts the search to regular files only (that is, not directories, socket, device files etc.)

Answer (score 0):

In general, I would use shell globbing to generate the list of files that you wanted to act on, then perform a read & test in order to decide whether to perform the operation.

For (your) example:

```
for f in *
do 
  [ -f "$f" ] || continue
  read -p "mv $f to /tmp? "
  if [ $REPLY = "y" ]
  then 
    echo "moving $f to /tmp"
    # mv -- "$f" /tmp
  else 
    echo "not doing anything with $f"
  fi
done
```

Depending on your shell settings, this may or may not pick up dot-files (e.g. `.bashrc`).

You could vary this to taste -- to not echo for the "no" response; to allow for "y" or "Y" or "yes" or "yabadabadoo".